# Replace string in a file if line starts with another string

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed

How can I replace a string in a file if line starts with another string using sed?

For example, replace this line:

```
connection = sqlite://keystone:[YOURPASSWORD]@[YOURIP]/keystone
```

With this line:

```
connection = mysql://keystone:password@10.1.1.10/keystone
```

Answer (score 31):

Answer:

```
sed '/^start_string/s/search_string/replace_string/'
```

Information at http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses

Comment: I'm getting sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown option to `s' for doing this: sed '/^connection/s/sqlite://keystone:[YOURPASSWORD]@[YOURIP]/keystone/connection = mysql://keystone:keystone@10.1.1.10/keystone'

Comment: Escape the `/` and `[` symbols in both search and substitution strings.

Comment: When escaping I get "sed: -e expression #1, char 137: unterminated `s' command"

Comment: Since your string(s) contain `/` characters, you can use an alternative delimiter instead: `sed '/^prefix/s#match#replace#'`. The `s` command reads the first character immediately following it and uses that for the delimiter, so you can choose one that isn't in either of your strings (and doesn't have some other meaning, like the ones used to build REs). Note that all three of them must be there, though, or you might also get an "unterminated command" error...

Comment: @twalberg - Using # as a delimiter indeed did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change an entire line which starts with a pattern and ends with enything else, you can use command `c` [description](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-list) Example

```
sed -i '/^connection = sqlite/c\connection = mysql://keystone:password@10.1.1.10/keystone' your_file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do simply this :

```
sed -ri 's/sqlite/mysql/g' YOURFILE
```

Comment: No, this will replace all `sqlite` and not only the one behind `connection`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^string1/ { s,string2,string3, }' file
```

This will replace string2 with string3 on all the lines that start with string1.

Comment: I'm trying this and it's waiting for some termination: sed '/^connection/ { s,connection = mysql://keystone:password@10.1.1.10/keystone } /etc/keystone/keystone.conf -- Getting > prompt

Comment: Hups! I forgot the comment.

Comment: TIL you can use commas instead of slashes.